# Victim of and victim to

Tags: prepositions

PREPOSITION WITH VICTIM
Please tell when to use victim of and when to use victim to.
For example He became victim .... circumstances.
Please tell the right prepostion to be used here.

Comment: Possible repetition of the question at: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/149426/victim-to-or-victim-of Kindly check the answer there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of 
https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/149426/victim-to-or-victim-of

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin: I don't think that's a valid closevote reason. You should either accept this as a valid ELU question, or vote to ***migrate*** it to ELL if that's where you think it belongs.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I implicitly think it belongs on ELL, but found the custom vote more useful for conveying a suitable answer to the original poster.

Answer (score 3):

You ***are a*** victim ***of*** some misfortune, but you can also ***fall*** victim ***to*** misfortune (no article).

Idiomatically those two forms are fairly universally recognised and observed, but the idiomatic preference for "to become" is less well-established, with both *become **a** victim **of** disease* and *become victim **to** disease* being perfectly acceptable to most native speakers.

Comment: + 1 Sure, you da man. I was just asked if I am a native speaker. [yuck, yuck]

Comment: Well, ***I*** knew that, but you don't give much away for free. For some reason I thought you were US-based (maybe based in *Texas*, but Lord knows why I'd ever have thought that). But checking your profile I see that although you give no "location" info, the fact that you're active on French, Portugese, and Spanish SO sites suggests to me that you're somewhere in *Europe*. Whatever - I think that knowing where other users come from is particularly relevant on ELU/ELL. More than with any other SO sites, your native language and / or "dialect" can make a difference. (UK ***Cockney***, me! :)

Comment: Well, a valiant effort. Bravo. Not in Europe or Latin America anymore. I am quadri-lingual, English mother tongue. And due to childhood British colonial influence and my father's Anglophilia, I was exposed to your side of the pond when they were dying the wool. But yes, a gringa. I like the simplicity and straightforwardness of your answer. Others can take heart....